# Button background in outlook web client not showing - HTML email development

Tags: html, email, html-email

Im having an issue with my button on outlook web client. It works on most other clients I have tried even outlook just not the web version.
I have even used a bulletproof button and it still doesn't show that background color.

Is there any solution to this or can it not be done?

My button:

```
<div><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#fa2951" fillcolor="#f52432">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Show me the button!</center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--><a href="http://testing"
style="background-color:#f52432;border:1px solid #fa2951;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Show me the button!</a></div>
```

Comment: I've tested this on Office 365 & Outlook.com on Explorer, Firefox & Chrome -- and all these web clients work well. (And Outlook apps, Android & iOS; and Outlook desktop) More information about your browser? Screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure but I think that is because your url is not correct.
I just spent one hour fighting against the same issue then changed my href to a random http://google.com and outlook finally print the button.